# Converting Beastly SQL Table into Multiple Access DBs Efficiently

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

I have a table in SQL (using SQL Server Management Studio 2008)  that's around 300,000,000 rows. Due to powers beyond my control this lovely table has to be converted to access datebases (plural since there is no way access will ever be able to handle so many rows).

I was hoping that rather than face the rather daunting tast of creating many csvs and importing them each into their own database there was a way to automate the process? Any ideas?

Thanks so much!

Comment: why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: @bluefeet "Powers beyond his control"

Comment: If this is truly a power beyond your control, I'd strongly suggest updating your resume.

Comment: Have you thought about a linked table from Access to SQL with ODBC?  It might actually handle that many rows

Comment: My feelings exactly. I guess SQL is much to scary for some people to handle?

Comment: The "powers that be" are completely INSANE to suggest such a thing. Keep the data in SQL Server and link to it from Access.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to leave it in SQL server and use an ODBC connection to access it from MS Access